# arcpy license: import arcserver is ignored at 10.3.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3, license

```
PS C:\> taskkill /F /IM python.exe
SUCCESS: The process "python.exe" with PID 14896 has been terminated.
PS C:\> python
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jun 30 2014, 16:08:48) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import arcserver
>>> import arcpy
>>> arcpy.ProductInfo()
u'ArcEditor'
```

Not sure what's up here.  I've had ArcGIS Server and ArcGIS Desktop installed simultaneously on my machine for a long time (10.1.1, 10.2.2, and now 10.3.1).  The above always worked fine to make sure arcpy scripts were using the ArcGIS Server license instead of grabbing a desktop license.  After upgrading both to 10.3.1, arcpy seems to completely ignore the server license and always look for a Desktop license.

---

Edited to show that no other module or process had already imported arcpy.

Comment: Are you sure that arcpy isn't getting imported before hand, perhaps in another module that's imported?

Comment: @EvilGenius Absolutely certain.  See edit.

Comment: Possibly related https://geonet.esri.com/thread/119004

Comment: @Luke - I think you may be right.  Looks like another esri bug where the only fix may be to wait until the next release.  Typical.  Still leaving question open for now....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an easy fix to this issue.

1. Uninstall 64-bit Background Geoprocessing for ArcMap
2. From python command line: `import arcserver` (This seems to setup several things on first run).
3. Re-install 64-bit Background Geoprocessing for ArcMap.

Everything works properly now.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [CheckProduct](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/checkproduct.htm) function to see what the return value is for `arcserver`:

```
arcpy.CheckProduct("arcserver")
```

If you did an upgrade, I've had strange issues pop up and had to do an uninstall/fresh install to resolve them.

Comment: arcpy.CheckProduct('arcserver')  
u'Available'  
Seems to find it just fine - just won't pull the license.  Really trying to avoid uninstall/reinstall.